# What is the diference between IP subnet mask 255.255.254 .0 ... or 255.255.255.0?

Tags: internet, ip, subnet

What is the diference between IP subnet mask 255.255.254.0 and 255.255.255.0?

Comment: @Ramhound subnet masks have nothing to do with public or private ip address ranges

Comment: those do look like subnet masks rather than subnets

Answer (score 9):

IPv4 addresses use 32 bits. For example the adddress `127.0.0.1` translated to binary is `01111111 00000000 00000000 00000001`.

For easy understanding instead of binary we, humans, use a decimal representation separating the 32 bits in 4 blocks of 8 bits.

Each block of 8 bits can go from `00000000`to `11111111`, or in decimal from `0` to `255`.

The IP address is divided in two parts: *network part* and *device part*.

1. The *network part* is common for all the devices on the same network
2. The *device part* is unique for each device.

*Who defines that division? The subnet mask.*

On every IP device you have an adddress and a subnet mask. The subnet mask only marks how many bits are fixed (*network part*) and how many bits are variable (*device part*) to use for your devices.

**An example:**

Suppose you choose for your network the address *192.168.0.0*. It is the *network part*.

- You decide to use the netmask *255.255.255.0* (on binary each 255 is 11111111 and each 0 is 00000000). It means that you decided to use the last **8 bits** of the address for your devices. 8 binary bits gives you 256 decimal, so you can have 256 addresses for the devices on your network ranging from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.0.255`. In real life you can't use the first and the last so you are in this case limited to 254 addresses.
- You change the network mask to *255.255.254.0*. Now you have **9 bits** for your devices (254 is 11111110). 9 binary bits translated to decimal gives you 512, so you can have 512 addresses for your devices ranging from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.1.255`. Just like before you can't use the first and the last so you are in this case limited to 510 addresses.

The netmask is chosen by the network administrator keeping in mind the size of the network (how many devices it will hold) and another design principles.

About private / public adddresses, IPv4 has 3 ranges that were defined for *private* networks, they are:

10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255

172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255

192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

Anything outside those ranges is *public* and can't be used for a network unless it was assigned by IANA or a IANA delegate.

Comment: Just to add a little clarity, if you have two computers on your network with addresses `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.1.1` and a netmask of `255.255.255.0`, they could not communicate with each other ( unless you set up a router ) because they are on two different logical networks, even though they share the same physical network.

Comment: Actually you can't use `192.168.1.0` and `92.168.2.255` for any device. It's network number and broadcast address accordingly

Comment: @psusi You're right.

Comment: @Nafscript Thanks for your correction .I was trying to oversimplify my answer, but added it for clarity.

Comment: More clarification: @Nafscript's information applies to this particular example only, nothing inherently wrong with addresses ending .0 and .255. This example itself is however invalid, a mask of /9 translates to 192.168.**0.0** to **1.255**. You can't arbitrarily start a range anywhere you like, which brings me to my next comment.

Comment: @jcbermu: Good answer, but IP addresses are *not* divided into "blocks of 8 bits". An IPV4 address is a single 32-bit number. The dotted decimal notation makes things simpler for some people to understand but severely confuses things in relation to CIDR and subnet masks that aren't cleanly divisible by 8. For non /n*8 masks it's a lot easier to envision both as a single string of 32 binary digits. Visualising it this way would also make it obvious why 1.0 to 2.255 is not a valid subnet.

Comment: @qasdfsaq It's true. I'm oversimplifying to make it understandable to someone without expertise on networks.

Comment: Case-study: once I saw this approach to assign coherent IP addresses to PCs and their IP-phone with something like: PC=`192.168.0.10` and its phone=`192.168.1.10`, so on all the others. For this the mask `255.255.254.0` was adopted.

Answer (score 2):

From the wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) you can see the three reserved private addresses ranges

```
IP address = 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255, subnet mask = 255.0.0.0 (corporate)
IP address = 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255, subnet mask = 255.240.0.0 (rarely seen) 
IP address = 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255, subnet mask = 255.255.0.0 or more common 255.255.255.0 (home use)
```

The subnet mask is really not relevant for public/private.

Comment: Agreed - updated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, subnet masks can be used for any private or public network. There's no rule or logic that indicates only certain subnet masks can be applied to certain public or private networks.

But to answer the question of what's different between 255.255.255.0 and 255.255.254.0...

255.255.255.0 allows for a total of 254 IP addresses to be used. 1 is for the subnet itself and another for the broadcast. Best example of this is the network 192.168.1.0. That is the ip of the subnet itself. 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254 are all valid IPs That can be assigned to client devices. Finally, 192.168.1.255 would be the broadcast address.

This contrasts with the subnet mask 255.255.254.0 in that it offers 510 valid IP addresses. Still one for the subnet itself and one for the broadcast.

Another example for this:

Network: 192.168.0.0
Broadcast: 192.168.1.255
Valid IPs: 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.1.254

Keep in mind, these ip ranges are just examples. You can use other IP addresses to subnet but the idea is the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

`255.255.255.0` is usually used for small private networks, yes. It assumes that there's only one router in the network and has a capacity of up to 253 or 254 clients. This is the most common setup where the router's IP address is `192.168.1.1`.

`255.255.254.0` is used for some two-router setups, such as modem-router or modem-router-router (where the modem is set to bridged mode). The routers could be at `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.0.1` each with their own sets of clients.